# Creating custom forms in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form

I have created a custom form in wordpress using POST method. However, upon submission I am getting 'Page does not exist error'...I added a custom page 'custompage1.php' in the theme directory that I am using in form action. It will be great if you can look into the code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Meal Planner</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php function checkregion($Region) 
    { 
   SWITCH ($Region) 
   { case "North": 
    echo "test1"; 
  break; 
 case "South": 
 echo "test2"; 
 break; 
 case "East": 
 header( 'location:https://www.test3.com/'); 
 break; 
 case "West": 
header( 'location: https://www.test4.com/'); 
break; 
} } 
 checkregion($Region); ?>
    <form action="../custompage1.php " method="POST">
        <method="POST">
            <p>Name</p>
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <p>Email</p>
            <input type="text" name="email">
            <p>Phone</p>
            <input type="text" name="phone">
            <p>Dropdown Box</p>
            <select name="Region" size="1">
                <option value="North">North</option>
                <option value="South">South</option>
                <option value="East">East</option>
                <option value="West">West</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
            <input type="reset" value="CLEAR">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: echo getcwd(); will tell you where the file is located.  Then you can at least establish that the path is correct.

Comment: What is the location of custompage1.php file? have you put this in theme directory or root directory ?

Comment: See here for getting dir in wp : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory

Comment: custompage1.php is located in theme directory

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_template_directory_uri()` to get the path of the theme directory as accessible via a browser. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/

```
<form action="<?= get_template_directory_uri() ?>/custompage1.php" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

Worth pointing out, though, that if you're using a child theme, you should use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a ton...it worked! However, the switch case is still not working...neither the echo command is working nor the header function is redirecting to the mentioned URL...Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: @Bot123 no worries! Is that `switch` statement from your custompage1.php? You would need to change the function call to `checkregion($_POST['Region']);`. Also, if you are outputting the HTML tags before calling the switch statement, the redirect will fail because headers have already been sent - move your PHP above the HTML.